# Tomcat Server Memory Leaks

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat7

I tried to run my Tomcat 7 server in debug mode it is almost started but immediated it went stopped.

you can find some logs below:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 22573 ms
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:653)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/dnweb.myeclipse.bak] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/DNClientWeb] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/DNClientWeb] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 27, 2012 4:56:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
```

After starting my server it went back to stop mode. These are the memory leaks problem. if it is how can i solve this.

Any sugessions, highly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat not starting is probably a problem of the port already being use as @ThorstenDittmar already suggested, otherwise Tomcat would die with some `OutOfMemoryError`.

For the memory leaks, you can try to find out which Instances remain in memory and prevent the old class loaders from being garbage collected by looking at a JVM heap dump with Java Visual VM. Check out [this article](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/) that explains how to find the old class loaders and the instance that still references them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all ports required to run Tomcat are free. The log message indicates that one of the ports Tomcat tries to use is already in use by another application.

Comment: i am just running one application using myeclipse.

Comment: As you can read here, Tomcat tries to listen on port 8005 and that does not work: `SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`. So port 8005 must already be occupied by some program.

Comment: If you're on linux, run `netstat -tulpen` as root to see which process occupies this port.

Comment: i am in windows using myeclipse.

Comment: i ran the netstat command. No process occupied this port. i have changed to port 8090 and it is not shown here.

Comment: Another possible solution is that Tomcat is prevented from opening the ports by the integrated Windows Firewall.

Answer (score -1):

Change port in server.xml directory   conf/

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
```